# What are continuous linear functionals on the product of Banach spaces?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Consider Banach spaces $\mathcal B_\alpha$ where $\alpha \in I$, some indexing set. They have continuous dual spaces $\mathcal B_\alpha^\ast$. I am interested in the space $\mathcal B=\Pi_{\alpha\in I}\mathcal B_\alpha$ with the product topology and its continuous dual $\mathcal B^\ast$. If $I$ is finite, then if $\ell\in \mathcal B^\ast$, then it is not hard to show that $\ell(v_1,...,v_n)=c_1 \ell_1(v_1)+...+c_n \ell_n(v_n)$ for some $\ell_i\in \mathcal B_i$. But what if $I$ is countable or even larger?

Comment: Your notation takes the tensor product but your title talks about the product; which one are you interested in?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Just normal product, fixed

Comment: Your question is still a little ambiguous here; the phrase "the product topology" makes it not entirely clear whether you're talking about the Banach space product or the topological vector space product. These are not the same (the Banach space product requires boundedness) and the Banach space product doesn't have the product topology. For example, the product of countably many copies of $\mathbb{C}$ is the space of bounded functions $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{C}$ equipped with the sup norm, so convergence is uniform convergence, whereas convergence in the product topology is pointwise.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I mean the actual product (pointwise convergence) topology.

Comment: Every continuous linear functional on $\prod_{\alpha\in I} B_\alpha$ is a **finite** sum of functionals of the form $\varphi_\alpha\circ \pi_\alpha$ for $\varphi_\alpha\in B_\alpha^*$ and the projections $\pi_\alpha$.

Comment: @Jochen Thanks. Do you have a proof?

Comment: The proof is rather routine: A continuous linear functional is bounded on some neighbourhood $U$ of $0$ and such a neighbourhood only restricts finitely many components of a family $(x_\alpha)_{\alpha\in I}$, i.e., $U$ contains a product $\prod_{\alpha\in I} U_\alpha$ where $U_\alpha$ are $0$-neighbourhoods in $B_\alpha$ and only finitely many satisfy $U_\alpha\neq B_\alpha$. Then put $\varphi_\alpha = \phi\circ i_\alpha$ where $i_\alpha:B_\alpha\to\prod_{\beta\in I}B_\beta$ puts $x\in B_\alpha$ into the $\alpha$'s components and fills up with zeros.